# Populating an excel column if some condition is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Please see the excel image:

[image]

I want to populate the Price Column with $250 if the Tier is 1, $200 if the Tier is 2 and $150 if the Tier is 3.

How do I do that? I tried the IF and COUNTIF functions but to no avail.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Change `Price A:` to `1`, `Price B:` to `2`, and `Price C:` to `3` and use a simple Vlookup to return the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your example starts at A1. You can use INDEX since the prices are in order:

```
=INDEX($B$10:$B$12,B2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function:VLOOKUP.
VLOOKUP looks for an item in a list and gets that item or another item in the same row.

using your sheet as a model where "Team" is in A1 and Price A is in A10.  If you add a column in between the name of the price and the actual price with the tier number in B10 to B12.

In C2

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, $B$10:$C$12, 2, 0)
```

This says to lookup the item in B2 (the number "1") in the section of the sheet in B10 to C12 and return the 2nd item in the row that matches.

One of the nice things about VLOOKUP is that order of either list doesn't matter.